# How to join SQL tables where value is Between min and max value

Tags: join

I am currently looking to join two tables together based on an IP and IP range. Both the IP and Range are currently stored as BIGINT.

For example we have a table MasterData with IPs in integer format [IPInteger] and we have another table called IPInformation which has all IP data but also has [start_ip_int] and [end_ip_int] range.

What I would like to to is join all the data in MasterData and All the data in the IPInformation based on the IPInteger being within the range of [start_ip_int] and [end_ip_int] on the IPInformation table.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, do you want a join between the tables in question using `ON x.IPInteger between y.start_ip_int and y.end_ip_int`?

Comment: @Lennart yes thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the SQL Server version in steps to work on IPs Range this might help you to convert in SqL

**Step 1: Create function [[usp_stringpart]](https://connectsql.wordpress.com/author/lionofdezert/page/13/) in your Database**

```
Create By: Aasim Abdullah
Description: Function takes a string and section number of string which
is required and separator, which separates different
sections of given string

Create FUNCTION [dbo].[usp_stringpart]
    (
      @InputString NVARCHAR(1000),
      @Section SMALLINT,
      @Separator NCHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @StartPosition INT,
            @EndPosition INT,
            @Cycle INT,
            @ResultString NVARCHAR(1000)
        SELECT  @Cycle = 0, @StartPosition = 0
        WHILE @Cycle < @Section - 1
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @StartPosition = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @InputString,
                                                   @StartPosition) + 1
                IF @StartPosition = 1 
                    SELECT  @Cycle = @Section
                ELSE 
                    SELECT  @Cycle = @Cycle + 1
            END
        SELECT  @EndPosition = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @InputString,
                                         @StartPosition)
        SELECT  @ResultString = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputString,
                                                      @StartPosition,
                                                      CASE @EndPosition
                                                        WHEN 0
                                                        THEN ( LEN(@InputString) + 1 )
                                                             - @StartPosition
                                                        ELSE ( @EndPosition - @StartPosition )
                                                      END)))
        RETURN @ResultString
    END
```

**Step 2: Add Column to save integer value of IPs**

```
ALTER TABLE TableContainIPs ADD IPIntegers BIGINT
```

**Step 3: Convert IPs to Integers**

```
UPDATE TableContainIPs
SET  IPIntegers  = CAST(
                        (CAST( TableContainIPs.dbo.usp_stringpart(REPLACE(IP,',',''),1,'.')AS BIGINT) *100000000000) 
                        +(CAST(TableContainIPs.dbo.usp_stringpart(REPLACE(IP,',',''),2,'.') AS BIGINT) *100000000)
                        +(CAST(TableContainIPs.dbo.usp_stringpart(REPLACE(IP,',',''),3,'.') AS BIGINT) *100000)
                        +(CAST(TableContainIPs.dbo.usp_stringpart(REPLACE(IP,',',''),4,'.')AS BIGINT) *100)
                       AS BIGINT)
 FROM TableContainIPs
```

**Step 4: Get IPs**

```
select P.IP, S.*
FROM  TableContainIPs P 
inner JOIN IPLibrary S  
ON P.IPIntegers BETWEEN s.IPasINTFrom AND s.IPasINTTo
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for your help, works like a charm